# Using sessions via Express and MongoDB, why can I only connect once to a route unless I change my session secret?

Tags: macos, session, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have an application in Express.js that I'm running on port 5000. I've been working on it for a while and it's been all good. Recently something went wrong though and it might be related to upgrading to Mountain Lion. I'm not sure.

To simplify the app, I just have one sample GET route set up right now:

```
  app.get('/', function(req, res){
    console.log('made it here');
    res.end('Hey there');
  });
```

For some reason, when I try to connect via a web browser (chrome, safari), it won't connect more than once. But if I connect by telnetting to the port directly and issuing a GET / , I get the response I was expecting (because no sessions are in play I assume).

Also, if I change my session secret, I can connect to it once/again via a browser, then subsequent refreshes never hit the route (200 is never logged for that route), until I change the secret again.

Here's how I have my session set up:

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
var mongoCon = require('connect-mongodb');
var session = express.session({
  store: new mongoCon({
      db: mongoose.connection.db
    , maxAge: 300000
  }), secret: 'donut' 
});
app.use(session);
```

EDIT: If I use MemoryStore instead of Mongo for my session store, it works fine.

Again, this has been working fine for weeks. I have recently updated to Mountain Lion. I've also reinstalled npms, but verified that I'm running the same version of connect-mongodb, mongoose, express, etc as before. I have this same code base running on an Ubuntu box and it seems fine. So maybe it's a Mac problem.

I realize this is a crazy question without a ton of good detail, but I'm kinda at a loss here. Any ideas on what to look for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out that it is related to the version of Mongoose I was using. I was using the latest version of mongoose (3.0.2) on my Mac, and 2.7.2 on Ubuntu. I'm guessing that something in the `mongoose.connection.db` object has changed. I will verify when I have a chance.

Thought I had tried that, but I must've mixed up versions at some point.

Hopefully someone from the Mongoose team (aheckmann maybe) will see this and let me know if it's something I can fix on my end or if it's a problem with connect-mongodb, etc.